# SQL query to select records based on the latest date

Tags: sql

I have 2 invoice numbers and the latest date for each invoice number. example given below.
I want to fetch the latest record(let say Instance_ID, System_ID and Customer) for each invoice number, i.e. it should fetch 2 rows of data.
for example:

```
invoice_number   received_date_latest
09867              8/4/2015
98543              8/6/2015
```

Could somebody please help me with the SQL query.

Regards

Comment: What database are you using? Which version?

Comment: Is this the expected result? then post the sample data

Comment: Please describe more.

Comment: select distinct invoice_number, MAX (received_date), etc1, etc2 from My_Table group by invoice_number, etc1, etc2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You may retrieve the records in order by method.i.e order by asc or desc.

Comment: yes. But in our project, there might be multiple records for one invoice with different dates. We want to select the latest record for that invoice

Answer (score 0):

`Select TOP 2 * From YourTableName order by YourDateColumn desc;`